# can someone help me why this code fails at c_orders (c_custkey, c_count) when executed in Mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

```
select c_count, count(*) as custdist
from
(
    select c_custkey, count(o_orderkey)
    from customer left outer join orders
    on c_custkey = o_custkey and o_comment not like '%special%requests%'
    group by c_custkey
) as c_orders (c_custkey, c_count)
group by c_count
order by custdist desc, c_count desc;
```

Comment: What is the exact error which you are getting when executing this query?

Comment: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select c_count, count(*) as custdist from ( select c_custkey, count(o_orderke' at line 1 0.000 sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
select c_orders.c_count, count(*) as custdist
from
(
    select c_custkey, count(o_orderkey) as c_count
    from customer left outer join orders
    on c_custkey = o_custkey and o_comment not like '%special%requests%'
    group by c_custkey
) as c_orders
group by c_orders.c_count
order by custdist desc, c_orders.c_count desc;
```

I saw two problems with your original query.  First, you were referring to a column in your outer query which does not exist in the temporary table in your inner query:

```
select c_count, ...
```

But this column does not exist in the inner temporary table.  Next, you had some strange syntax next to the alias for your temporary table:

```
) as c_orders (c_custkey, c_count)
```

You don't need whatever you had in parentheses, so I removed it.

Comment: The query you have posted worked. But can you please explain regarding the temporary table in inner query you were referring to.

Comment: It wasn't solved yet.Since it is the query published in TPCH and i still couldn't find why its wasn't being supported by Mysql.